# Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm new using React Native Navigation and I'm having a problem during the installation process for Android.

So i installed the package, and followed instructions until step 5.
Once there i add the code to MainApplication.java, but after doing that, i execute react-native run-android and i get the following error.

[image]

I read in other posts that the problem could be solved by executing
 `npm start -- --reset-cache` but that doesn't  work for me.

Im using react native navigation v1.1.298

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am facing the same problem. Looks like this library doesnt work properly with react-native version `> 0.49`. Because in previous react native versions it had **index.android.js**, **index.ios.js** and **index.js** but now it only generates a single index.js file.

You need to copy `index.js` file and duplicate 2 new files naming them `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js`

Note: If you are following any tutorial and have not added any routing code yet then you will get a blank screen after this step. Dont worry its just the Splash. Once you write navigation code it will work fine.

Comment: Who puts that in production? Jesus that's ugly but no other way.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encountering this issue on Windows while running Watchman file watch service, it is likely due to this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246

Upgrading jest to version => 21.0.0 fixes the root cause.
  This can be accomplished via `npm i react-native@0.50.0` which will cover RN's dependents up to that version as well as `npm i jest@21.2.0`

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question.

But the problem is probably because your java entry file doesn't have `getJSMainModuleName` function.
You can check this function if you create a new RN project.